# Vertical alignment of mat-grid-list

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm using angular 6.0.9

I want to create a very simple layout:

- At the very top of the page, two tabs to select between creating an item or viewing existing items.
- Creating an item is a straightforward form
- Viewing the items is a two row view: on the left the list of items, on the right a panel that gets updated with item details when something is selected in the left list.

Here is what my layout looks like:

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab>
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>View items</ng-template mat-tab-label>
        <!-- This list is for the 2 columns layout -->
        <mat-grid-list  cols="2" rowHeight="1:1" gutterSize="0">
            <!-- Firt column: the list of items -->
            <mat-grid-tile>
                <!-- Just to have some fancy borders around the item list, I put it in a mat-card -->
                <mat-card>
                    <!-- List of items -->
                    <mat-list>
                        <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of items">
                            ...
                        </mat-list-item>
                    </mat-list>
                </mat-card>
            </mat-grid-tile>
            <!-- Second column: selected item details -->
            <mat-grid-tile>
                <!-- The details of the item -->
                <mat-card>
                    ...
                <mat-card>
            </mat-grid-tile>
        </mat-grid-list>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab>
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>Create item</ng-template mat-tab-label>
        ...
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

I only have the following CSS, I added `width: 100%` otherwise the cards do not take up the whole column width.

```
mat-card {
    width: 100%;
}
```

I have two issues:

- First, **the columns are vertically centered** in the page. That is, the card for the item list and the card for the item details are not located right under the tab, but instead lay in the middle of the page.
- Second, I do not really understand how I should use material with angular. When comparing the documentation of material versus angular/material, I see that material has "mdc-layout-grid-cell-align", but I have no idea how to use that when using material/angular!

I tried adding `layout-align` or `mdc-layout-grid-cell-align` pretty much everywhere, in CSS and material-specific tags. No success.

Comment: Try `mat-card { width: 100%; height: 100%; }`  And about using MD web components, you should follow their offcial docs to use it inside angular https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web

Comment: Can you try Angular Flex Layout?